# Creating and linking div tags in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create two div tags(div1 and div2) side by side in a single html page. In the div1 I'm creating 2 anchor tags(Create and Insert). And in the div2 I want to create 2 div tabs (tab1 and tab2). I want to address the create to tab1 and insert to tab2. Can someone help me please?

```
.container {
width: 80%;
height: 200px;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
}
.one {
width: 15%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
}
.two {
margin-left: 15%;
height: 200px;
}



<section class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <a href="tab1">Create</a>
    <a href="tab2">Insert</a>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div id="tab1">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="cpp">C++</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="java">java</button>
         <div id="cpp" class="tabcontent">Create in C++</div>  
         <div id="java" class="tabcontent">Create in java</div>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="cpp">C++</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="java">java</button>
          <div id="cpp" class="tabcontent">Create in C++</div>  
          <div id="java" class="tabcontent">Create in java</div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[I want my tab to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faOcI.png)

Answer (score -1):

I hope, this code is help full

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">message</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">settings</div>
  </div>

</div>
```